# Finding max of dates

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some dates in some different format.

```
date1 = 2015-05-27T04:51:12.715Z
date2 = 2015-05-27T04:51:12.782Z
date3 = 2015-05-27T04:51:12.865Z
```

Dont know what this format means specially the last 4 characters.And how would I find the maximum of these dates in Javascript

Comment: The `Z` stands for 'Zulu time', which is equivalent of GMT/UTC. The preceding 3 numbers are the fraction of the second.

Comment: And what does "max" mean ?

Comment: Max means the maximum of all dates. Eg : In above code its date3

Comment: from where you get these data ?

Answer (score 1):

Just sort the array and get the first item

```
var date1 = '2015-05-27T04:51:12.715Z';
var date2 = '2015-05-27T04:51:12.782Z';
var date3 = '2015-05-27T04:51:12.865Z';

var array = [date1, date2, date3];


array.sort(function(a,b) {
    return new Date(a) < new Date(b);
});

var max = array[0];
```

Comment: Converting to Date beforehand and then pushing in array following by  `Math.max.apply(Math, array)` performs better. Just saying :)

Comment: @years_of_no_light - already thought of that, but it returns the timestamp and not the actual string, and I'm not sure what is needed here